# an efficent version similar to strstr

Tags: c, string, algorithm, implementation

here is a general implementation

```
int stridx (char[] src, char[] str){
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=0;i < (src.len - str.len);i++){
      for(j=i,k=0; str[k] != '\0' && str[k] == src[i]; j++,k++);
      if( k> 0 && str[k]=='\0') return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The worst case of the algorithm could be n^2, if we have aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa (assuming both src and str are very long, and the length of them is very close).

Can I have a better algorithm?

Comment: It's `O(nk)`, not `O(n^2)`.  And I think your condition needs to be `i<=src.len-str.len`.  But what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Boyer-Moore algorithm, which is O(n).  [Here's](http://srcvault.scali.eu.org/cgi-bin/Syntax/Syntax.cgi?BoyerMoore.c) sample C code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to calculate the length of the strings :

```
char *strr(char *s1,char *s2)
  {
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;s1[i];i++)
        if(s1[i]==s2[0])
            for(j=0;s1[i+j]==s2[j];j++)
                if(!s2[j+1]) return &s1[i];
    return NULL;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm is another linear time algorithm. OTOH, the simple algorithms stay because in practise they are faster for most of the strings people actually search with.